# Android V7 Support PopupMenu Exception

Tags: android, exception, popupmenu

I'm trying to implement the V7 support PopupMenu but I'm getting an exception while constructing it.

From my Activity class:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;

...

public void showPopup(View v)
{
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    ...
}
```

The exception I get is:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout

I took a peak inside of the android-support-v7-appcompat.jar in my lib directory and the appcompat folder within that jar is empty. That would explain the exception.

I downloaded the same jar from the internet just in case mine was somehow corrupt and I see the same thing. The appcompat folder is empty.

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are sure you have imported the appcompat_v7 support library and are referencing it correctly?

Comment: There should not be an `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` in your project's `libs/` directory. `appcompat_v7` is an Android library project, not a simple JAR.

Comment: Thank you. I was following the Android documentation for adding libraries without resources, in which it just says to copy the jar over. Turns out I needed to follow the directions for adding libraries *with* resources.